# JAX-WS Service is not allowed to be child of element HTTP

Tags: service, configuration, jax-ws, cxf, mule

I'm trying to made creating a JAX-WS Service in mule i do  a sample from  [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF#BuildingWebServiceswithCXF-CreatingaJAX-WSService)

I get error in the configuration: Element: JAX-WS Service is not allowed to be child of element HTTP 
 i install mule 3.3.1 but Mule Studio CE uses mule 3.3.0

```
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:63081/hello" exchange-pattern="request-response">
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.example.HelloWorld"/>
</http:inbound-endpoint>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Studio used to have some problem with nested elements, as explained in this [Jira](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-2297)

However that has been fixed in the soon to be released [Mule 3.4](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/announcing-mule-3-4-beta/).